# The wait operation timed out

Tags: sql-server, azure, .net, indexing

I have encountered this problem when running a Data-fill routine for a Data-set Data-adapter in C# which uses a stored procedure written in SQL Server Azure.

The SQL Server stored procedure executed directly from SQL Server Management Studio took only 3 seconds and it executed fine. As a work around, I executed "`exec sp_updatestats`" on the Azure database and then the Data-fill routine worked fine!

Got a bit puzzled here to understand who is playing up. SQL server can execute the stored procedure in 3 seconds, but the C# Data-set Data-fill routine time out.

Even though the problem is solved, could someone explain why the re-indexing (or update statistics) directly effecting the the Data-set or Data-adapters fill routine where the Stored procedure result can executed without timeout?